# output of mysql is showing corrupt data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have saved hindi data in mysql using collate utf8_general_ci, but output is showing corrupt data. It was working before i updated my pc. but now same code is not working. i have tried changing collate to utf8mb4_general_ci. But still same issue persist. Please help..
below is the code:--

```
`<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "****";
try{
$db = new 
PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydb;collation=utf8_general_ci",$username,$password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Connection failed: ". $e->getMessage();
}
?>`
```

Comment: *but output is showing corrupt data.* I think that not data corrupted but the output shows it incorrectly. *i have tried changing collate to utf8mb4_general_ci.* Collation effects string compare only. And I'm surprised that you have changed the collation without the charset convertion...

Comment: I have tried it but no use, even i tried utf8_unicode_ci and utf16_general_ci. But not working for me.  About charset conversion....i have done that in html file at meta tag as well as in mysql table structure. what else need to be done?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer????